# Adding new rspec to an old rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, helper

I have an old rails project that I want to add some new rspec to. I am a hobby developer. The rails 5.1.0.rc2 project originally was properly rspec initialized (3.5.0) before recently reaquired from git using rvm on an old linux machine.

however, the project is currently not reading the project .rspec file, or any file that is called with require at the top of the spec file (require 'rails_helper' etc)

```
rspec signing_in_spec.rb 
/home/cjlmb/*/spec/features/signing_in_spec.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails_helper (LoadError)
    from /home/cjlmb/*/spec/features/signing_in_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/cjlmb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@*/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in `load'
    from /home/cjlmb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@*/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/cjlmb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@v/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1433:in `each'
    from /home/cjlmb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@*/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1433:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/cjlmb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@*/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:100:in `setup'
    from /home/cjlmb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@*/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
    from /home/cjlmb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@*/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
    from /home/cjlmb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@*/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /home/cjlmb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@*/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/cjlmb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@*/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /home/cjlmb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@*/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/cjlmb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@*/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    from /home/cjlmb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@*/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

I have some old specs in the project that was working properly originally in '17.

Any obvious answer as to why it is not now?  It's possible it's something basic like having to have local server running etc.

Comment: it's saying it can't load rails_helper.rb. This is a file that became standard in Rspec installations in recent years. Do you have this file in the /spec/ folder? If not, you'll need to put it there. What should it contain? Well you can look in the RSpec source code, or else create a new rails app and see what is in the rails_helper.rb file. There's no quick answer like "run rspec:install", you just have to read and respond to the error messages.

Comment: Actually, it's some other problem because any require line at the top of a spec results in the same error

Comment: then the loading problem is probably related to the fact that it doesn't appear to be reading the .rspec file

Comment: how do you invoke rspec... is it executing the bin/rspec executable or the executable from the gem?

Comment: it doesn't read any require * files.  to invoke i go to the spec sub folder, type rspec * or rspec filename_spec.rb. since i cant reach any helper files, while going trhough the rspec book i have have code like c.color = true,   c.example_status_persistence_file_path = 'spec/features/examples.txt',   c.filter_run_when_matching(focus: true) in the configure block at the top of each spec file, as well as another color assignment, because i can't read the red on this old screen

Comment: bundle exec rspec is same result

Comment: any difference if you run rspec from the app root (vs spec folder)?... I think this is how it's normally done

Comment: my .rspec file has these two lines: --colour
--require spec_helper (each line starts with the double-hyphen)

Comment: Goddamn, that got it. Because I wasn't running from the app root it couldn't find the required files. Should have emoticons on here but I guess that wouldn't be professional, otherwise I'd use a palm to the forehead or something.  It's been a significant amount of time since I've programmed, much appreciated for helping out.

Comment: If you want to answer the question I'd mark it as correct etc.

Comment: seems like something that is trivial, or should have a more specified return.  maybe switch 'cannot load file' with 'cannot load file because it cannot be found, likely because you're not running it from root, didn't you read the fm'.

Comment: ha ha glad you got it going... at least until the next problem... have a great day!